# Passing templated class?

Tags: c++

I'm working on performing some operations on a polymorphic doubly-linked list, and I seem to be having some issues with that.

I'm trying to pass a instance of the class to this function:

```
void performoperator(List<string> list, string operator, int &OpCount){
 //...
}
```

and I'm trying to call it as such:

```
 List<string> list;
 //...
 performoperator(list, temp, OpCount);
```

The compiler doesn't appear to accept the way in which I'm calling the function, and I'm fairly certain the issue is with the templated class somehow. What am I doing improperly?

**Edit**: Resolved, won't let me post as a solution as I'm a new user.
The issue was the I needed to pass the list by reference.

Comment: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Dlist<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::Dlist<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(class Dlist<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > const &)" (??0?$Dlist@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)

Comment: Only occurs when attempting to call the function. If I comment that line out compiles properly.

Comment: It is looking for a copy constructor, used to copy the list parameter. Strangely it is call Dlist, and not List. Why?

Comment: Your error message, simplified: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: Dlist<string>::Dlist<string>(Dlist<string> const &)"`

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. The function required me to pass the list by reference, which is something I didn't realize (as it's a void function, and I was performing an operation on the list). (The class is called, Dlist, Bo, I was just simplifying some syntax, for posting);

Answer (score 3):

```
void performoperator(List<string> list, string operator, int &OpCount)
                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

`operator` is a reserved keyword in C++; you cannot use it as a variable name.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that, didn't mean to have that there, but the issue remains.

Comment: I once read a question where a guy had in his code something like `int operator = (ASSIGN_OP);` :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:  You put template code in cpp file not in your header file

Comment: You're correct, something I was required to do. Managed to find the solution to my problem however (above). Thanks!